# Android ABS IcsSpinner doesn't show items popup

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ABS in my project and I'm trying to using `IcsSpinner` instead of `Spinner`, after define that in xml and set Adapter popup doesn't show popup or dialog after click on `IcsSpinner` and I have only see first item of array into `IcsSpinner`

```
    <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_panel_numbers"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_spinner_background"
        android:popupBackground="@color/spinner_background_dialog" />
```

My code:

```
String[]             actions = new String[]{
                                 "Bookmark",
                                 "Subscribe",
                                 "Share"
                                 };
IcsAbsSpinner spinner_panel_numbers = (IcsAbsSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_panel_numbers);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, actions);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner_panel_numbers.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**UPDATE:**
[image]

color for spinner is :

```
<color name="spinner_background_dialog">#cccccc</color>
```

trying to use `wrap_content` doesn't open or show popup

UPDATE 2:

I have custom theme in application and I'm define that by below code in manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Tsms"
```

My custom theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Tsms" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.TsmsABS" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.TsmsICSABS" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/shape_button_press</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:width">200dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I don't see any change to show popup. but after change custom theme to `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"` that works fine and spinner can be show popup

Comment: Have you tried using android:layout_width="wrap_content" ?

Comment: also which color passing in `spinner_background_dialog`?

Comment: using `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"` theme for Activity in manifest?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK work fine sir. unfortunately i'm define custom theme and i dont want to use `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"` directly in manifest. how to add to current theme?

Comment: Use `parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock"` in custom theme xml like `<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">`